# Accidently deleted Home Folder

Tags: unity, home-directory

How do I get the Home Folder back and the icon? I'm using Unity desktop environment.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; I can hardly imagine you actually have no home folder. Do you mean the Launcher icon is missing / accidentally removed?

Comment: Yes, i accidently removed unlocked it from laucher, but its fine now i reinstalled ubuntu.

Comment: WOW, that is too much work!! You didn't actually remove the folder, only the Files *icon* from the launcher. You could have searched for "nautilus" in Dash, open it and simply lock it to the Launcher again. Appr. 5 seconds of work. A pitty I didn't see your question earlier.

Comment: To the close-voters: I think it is useful to keep this question open. Someone else might make the same mistake!

Comment: Well i had 14.04 installed and it was MESSING up like crazy so i was gonna reinstall ubuntu anyways :/ It seems 14.04 only doesnt work for me

Comment: Would you mind if I posted it as an answer? It could prevent too much work for others.

Comment: Fine by me :P go ahead

Comment: Voted to leave open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment I understand you removed *the icon* from the Launcher. This does *not* remove your home folder, only its icon from the Launcher.

To get it back, just open Dash, search for "nautilus" and drag the icon on to the launcher and you're done:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a recovery for your deleted files. I advise you to use R-studio for Linux which is a free version of R-studio data recovery tools.

R-Studio for Linux recovers files:

Deleted from the computer and emptied from the Trash
Corrupted due to a virus, power failure or sudden shutdown
From disks that have been Re-formatted to the same file system or a different file system
Damaged and have bad sectors-R-Studio for Linux creates an image of the entire disk and recovers it from there to prevent further physical damage to the disk
You can download from [here.](http://www.r-tt.com/data_recovery_linux/Download.shtml)

Comment: Says i dont have permission to download...

Comment: Everything has been messing up since i upgraded to 14.04 LTS... should i downgrade back to 12.04?

Comment: Are you not admin? Also no , I would not suggest downgrading, i have the same os as you and dont have any problems. Try repeating the steps as root.

Comment: Well im the only user and yea i am admin usually it asks for me to type pass but when i upgraded kinda messed up my kernel version says 3.8 what does yours say? i read it was suppose to say atleast 3.10 when you upgrade to 14.04